# C++ "infinite" length text

Tags: c++, string, text

my task is to make a program that can store arbitrary long text in c++.
I have no idea how to solve this. 
Also, you cannot use STL.
someone please help

Comment: -1 You need to make more of an effort before people will help. You cannot simply post your homework expecting someone to do it for you, this is not that kind of site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. allocate initial buffer (`malloc()`)
2. store data into buffer until full (`strcpy()`, `strcat()`, `memcpy()`...)
3. reallocate to a bigger buffer (`realloc()`)
4. goto 2